# C#. Вывод текста в tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#

C#. Есть таблица 20x6 созданная в tablelayoutpanel. Каждая ячейка элемент Label. Как вывести текст в ячейку с конкретным адресом?

Comment: В ячейку - никак. Ищите нужный вам label, выводите в него.

Comment: По имени label не интересно, хотелось бы по координате. В примере обучения c# есть заполнение, но только всей таблицы посредством foreach из копии в памяти.

Comment: если вам надо по координате найти label, то вы можете, например, при создани этих label заносить их в массив и потом в массиве получать по индексу. Или заносить в словарь. Или вы можете label назвать (там у него вроде поле Name есть) "myLabel_X_Y" и после  получать все контролы на форме и искать по названию. Способов море, это чисто полет фантазии.

Comment: То есть, насколько я понял, в контейнере нет возможности обращаться к элементам содержимого контейнера по координате контейнера? Спасибо.

Comment: я этого не знаю, так как я даже не понимаю о чем вы вообще пишете. Вы ведь когда меня спрашиваете о чем то, вы представляете себе свой написанный код, а я не то, что код ваш не видел, я даже не в курсе что за платформа у вас. Потому когда вы спрашиваете про возможно/невозможно что либо по координатам, я не понимаю о чем вообще речь и что за координаты.

Comment: Label [,] fb=new Label[6,20];
Label temp=new Label();
foreach (Control control in tablelayoutpanel.Controls)
{
 temp = control as Label;
 fb[temp.TabIndex / 20, temp.TabIndex % 20] = temp;
}

Вот решение моей задачи. Вопрос закрыт, спасибо за советы.

Comment: Не знаю как правильно отформатировать ответ.(

Comment: внизу есть поле для ответа, вы можете там свой ответ разместить.